# read() function in C with fixed size buffer fail to return the expected result

Tags: c

From what I understand, `read()` function in C should just read data that user asked for, so because file is seekable to iterate over a file the code should be like:

```
int f = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
// buffer size 10
char file_buffer[10];
size_t file_nbytes;
file_nbytes = sizeof(file_buffer);

while(read(f, file_buffer, file_nbytes) != 0) {
  printf("%s\n", (char *) file_buffer);
}
```

but if the buffer size is fixed, during the last batch of read, there will be some chars from the previous batch that repeatedly print out, e.g.:

```
Previous batch:

Read input (descriptor 3): 10 chars
g and news

Last batch:

Read input (descriptor 3): 3 chars
.
nd news
```

where the `nd news` is printed out repeatedly.

I tried to clear the buffer before every read but it still didn't work, so how should I fix this problem?

Comment: You should be using `fgets()` to read a text file. `read()` is best for binary files. You are getting funny results because you aren't reading a whole line, which might or might not contain a string terminator `'\0'` on which `printf()` depends, but probably not.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will keep that in mind. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about clearing the buffer, you lose efficiency for no reason. Just null terminate before printing. `read` returns the number of bytes actually read which is what you need for that. E.g.

```
ssize_t n_read;
while((n_read = read(f, file_buffer, file_nbytes-1)) > 0) {
    file_buffer[n_read] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", file_buffer);
}
```

Note that I check `> 0` as `read` may return -1. And you don't need to cast `file_buffer` to a `char*`

Comment: Needs to read `file_nbytes-1` otherwise the terminator is written beyond the array limit.